# Create a simple job spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, jobs

I created a spring boot project. 
I use spring data with elastic search. 
The whole pipeline: controller -> service -> repository is ready.

I now have a file that represents country objects (name and isoCode) and I want to create a job to insert them all in elastic search.
I read the spring documentation and I find that there's too much configuration for such a simple job.
So I'm trying to do a simple main "job" that reads a csv, creates objects and insert them in elastic search.

But I have a bit of trouble to understand how injection would work in this case:

```
@Component
public class InsertCountriesJob {

private static final String file = "D:path\\to\\countries.dat";
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InsertCountriesJob.class);

@Autowired
public CountryService service;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LOG.info("Starting insert countries job");
    try {
        saveCountries();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void saveCountries() throws Exception {
    try (CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String[] values = null;
        while ((values = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
            String name = values[0];
            String iso = values[1].equals("N") ? values[2] : values[1];
            Country country = new Country(iso, name);
            LOG.info("info: country: {}", country);
            //write in db;
            //service.save(country); <= can't do this because of the injection
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Injection will not work because you don't have Spring Boot Application class and you cannot use main that way. You will need to use a Commandline runner.

Please read this. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-console-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on Simon's comment. Here's how I resolved my problem. Might help people that are getting into spring, and that are trying not to get lost.
Basically, to inject anything in Spring, you'll need a SpringBootApplication

```
public class InsertCountriesJob implements CommandLineRunner{

private static final String file = "D:path\\to\\countries.dat";
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InsertCountriesJob.class);

@Autowired
public CountryService service;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LOG.info("STARTING THE APPLICATION");
    SpringApplication.run(InsertCountriesJob.class, args);
    LOG.info("APPLICATION FINISHED");
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    LOG.info("Starting insert countries job");
    try {
        saveCountry();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    LOG.info("job over");
}

public void saveCountry() throws Exception {
    try (CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String[] values = null;
        while ((values = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
            String name = values[0];
            String iso = values[1].equals("N") ? values[2] : values[1];
            Country country = new Country(iso, name);
            LOG.info("info: country: {}", country);
            //write in db;
            service.save(country);
        }
    }
}


}
```